# Google Maps API: Detecting location and dropping a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using Google's example code for detecting a user's location, I setup a basic page that detects a user's location on a map. I also setup a separate page that drops a marker on a map at a specific coordinate. I want to combine these functions into one script. That is, I want to drop a marker on the map at the location detected, but I can't seem to get it to work. My code detects the user's location, but doesn't drop a marker. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm not familiar with Javascript, so I'm having trouble resolving the problem.

Below is Google's example code. What would I need to add to display the marker at initialLocation? I tried adding the following code:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initialLocation,
        map: map,
        title: "You are here"
});
```

[image: Google's example code]

Comment: This thing depends how you are calling functions and where you are putting code to create markers. You should put in function that is called after getting the initial position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [`setMap()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) after you've created the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: initialLocation,
    map: map,
    title: "You are here"
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: I tried adding that at the bottom before the last curly bracket, but no luck.

Comment: That's odd. Could you share some more code? Is `map` visible in the scope that you're creating the marker? (In the example code you provided `map` isn't global)

Comment: Try putting it after `map.setCenter(initialLocation);` in the sections that get the initial location in the middle of the code

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I guess I was trying to call a local variable as though it were global.

Comment: You're welcome! I suspect the `intialLocation` wasn't set at the time you were creating the marker - the callback functions passed to `getCurrentPosition()` are probably asynchronous.